# Valid RSS feed URL "is not authorized" in Thunderbird

Tags: bug, feed

An RSS feed URL such as [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=catholicism&sort=newest), [which validator.w3.org says is a valid feed](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fchristianity.stackexchange.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%3Ftagnames%3Dcatholicism%26sort%3Dnewest), "is not authorized" in Thunderbird 102.2.2 (64-bit).

Stack Exchange RSS URLs used to work in Thunderbird versions prior to circa July 2022.

Comment: That example RSS URL worked without problems when I tried it (stock installation of Thunderbird, 91.11.0, on Linux).

Comment: [A similar problem](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=3031947). Due to an add-on? Menu *"Tools"* → *"Add-ons and Themes"* → *"Extensions"*

Comment: User agent: [Thunderbird's User Agent](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Thunderbird#Securing). Menu *"Edit"* → *"Preferences"* → *"General"* → *"Config Editor..."* (scroll to the very bottom, right) → paste "general.useragent.override" (mine is empty/absent)

Comment: OT when the feed is hosted at feedburner.com see https://groups.google.com/g/feedburner/c/YvIA5cYyfIM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many requests, including to the RSS feed, stand a chance of getting blocked with a Forbidden error if you do not send a User-agent along with your request. If you're seeing that particular error, you'll want to check your system to make sure it is passing a User-agent along with the request.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good tip; yet there must be something else, as I've been unable to resolve this problem no matter how I set (or don't) the user agent string in Thunderbird. (Of course, the problem is ultimately Feedburner, rather than Thunderbird or SX, but even so.)